# Segue from button from UICollectionViewCell inside parent UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I use UICollectionViewCell with buttons inside parent UICollectionViewCell:

```
protocol DayCellDelegate
{
    func buttonTapped()
}

class SelectTimeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewSlider: UICollectionView!    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        collectionViewSlider?.register(DayCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionViewSlider.dataSource = self
        collectionViewSlider.delegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DayCollectionViewCell
        cell.dayTitle.text = String(indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
}

class DayCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, DayCellDelegate {

    func buttonTapped() {
        print("button clicked")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupDayTimeline(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupDayTimeline(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {

        let appsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()            
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 45)
            let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: width, height: height - 30), collectionViewLayout: layout)            
            return collectionView
        }() 
        addSubview(appsCollectionView)

        appsCollectionView.delegate = self
        appsCollectionView.dataSource = self

        appsCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "TimeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "timecell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timecell", for: indexPath) as! TimeCollectionViewCell
        cell.btnTime.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeSelected), for: .touchUpInside)
        }        
        return cell
    }

    func timeSelected(){
       //here I need perform segue for SelectTimeViewController
    }
}

class TimeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnTime: UIButton!    
    var delegate : DayCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func btnTimeClick(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.buttonTapped()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
```

How can I perform segue from DayCollectionViewCell?
I can't call self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "...", sender: info) in timeSelected() because UICollectionViewCell doesn't contain performSegue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a protocol for the controller which holds your collection view, this protocol will define the "cell delegate" and then you can call actions on the controller, I.e:

```
protocol DayCellDelegate
{
    func buttonTapped(...)
}
```

You create a property in the DayCellCollectionViewCell or its parent, you can name it delegate

```
var delegate : DayCellDelegate?
```

And then in the cellForItem method, when you can the cell, set the delegate to the controller and implement it:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

And finally in your cell's tap action, call:

```
self.delegate?.buttonTapped(...)
```

Hope that helps, if you need more specific guidance let me know.

Comment: Remember to make the delegate variable `weak` in order to avoid any possible cycles. I believe that to do this the protocol has to be limited to be only to `class`

Comment: DayCollectionViewCell needs to inherit from DayCellDelegate and conform to the protocol, meaning to have an implementation of buttonTapped as well